# Finding higher Ramsey numbers

Tags: ramsey-theory

How do mathematics go about finding larger Ramsey numbers such as R(5, 5)? How do they find upper bounds on these numbers?

Comment: A lower bound for $$R(l+1,l+1)$$ is $$R(l,l)+\left\lceil\frac{R(l,l)-l}{l-1}\right\rceil$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some ideas:**

A famous upper bound for any $k,l$ is from Erdos-Szekeres:

$R(k,l) \le \binom {k+l-2} {k-1}$.

In your case, $k=l=5$, so $R(5,5) \le \binom {8}{4}$

You can find some thoughts of Paul Erdos about Ramsey numbers in that [sheet](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/02_05_ramsey_and_erdos.pdf) aswell. It is generally hard to find such big numbers in a very exact way, we don't have many methods to do that.

Comment: The Erdos-Szekeres conjecture doesn't seem to be proven. Has it been?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Combinatorics/Bounds_for_Ramsey_numbers Here you can find it.